# Debugging Reinforcement Learning Model (MsPacman)

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm attempting to train an RL agent to play MsPacman in PyTorch. I've adapted the code from this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html) on the PyTorch page for my problem. The DQN has the following architecture:

```
DQN(
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
  (bn1): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (conv2): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
  (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (conv3): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (bn3): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (linear1): Linear(in_features=7040, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (linear2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=9, bias=True)
)
```

I'm using the actor (policy) and critic (target) method with replay memory which has the following settings:

- **Replay Buffer**: 100,000
- **Target Update**: Every 10,000 steps
- **Bath Size**: 128
- **Discount Rate**: 0.999

For the exploration trade-off I'm using epsilon-greedy with the following curve:
[image]

where the x-axis is the step number (in million) and y the probability of selecting a random action.

The update of the policy network looks like this:

```
# next_state_values = Q-values precited by the target network
# GAMMA = discount rate (0.999)
# reward_batch = rewards for the states
expected_state_action_values = (next_state_values * GAMMA) + reward_batch
```

Loss calculation:

```
# state_action_values = actions taken by the policy agent
# expected_state_action_values - this is calculated above
loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(state_action_values, expected_state_action_values.unsqueeze(1))
```

Updating the policy (gradients are clamped):

```
optimiser.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
for param in policy_net.parameters():
    param.grad.data.clamp_(-1, 1)
optimiser.step()
```

While training the agent I plot the duration of each episode shown below (the orange line shows the average of the previous 100 episodes):

[image]

After 4,000 episodes the agent isn't really progressing and gets stuck in corners like below:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see the episode rewards, as that is what the agent is optimising for. Is the agent getting stuck in corners from the beginning? If so, I would guess that the epsilon greedy policy (which is pretty much pure random at the beginning) is not implemented properly. I assume that the agent gets rewards for eating the dots, so it should be motivated to move around.

Try a pure random agent and see how that progresses, you can plot that as a baseline which will tell you if your agent is learning anything at all.